# Dictation not working in OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

I have enabled dictation in the preferences, but it fails to start.

When I tap <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>fn</kbd>, the Icon with three dots appears, and quickly disappears. I don't see a microphone.

My system is connected to the Internet with an ADSL router, through an Ethernet LAN. I have temporarily disabled the router firewall, but it does not seem to help.

My system is in French (but I think "Dictation" should work since it is indeed called '"Dictée")

How can I have logs?

What can I investigate?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it drove me crazy! This helped me:

1. Go to `~/Library/Preferences`
   ( <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> )
2. Locate `com.apple.assistant.plist` and move it to the Trash
3. Open *Dictation & Speech* preference panel, disable dictation
4. Reboot
5. Re-enable *Dictation & Speech*.

Voila!

**PS** This hint has the nicest side-effect: In Mail, all accounts used to be **offline** after sleep (Small triangle icons next to account), and would only come back on after quitting and restarting Mail.app. Now, all is well again. Ts!

Comment: +1 for your answer, but I can't confirm I can't formally accept it, because I did no specific actions, and Dication is working today.

Comment: Good to hear it works now! Can’t confirm you can’t accept? Yes please :) And merry Holidays to You.